# Python IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable

Tags: python, slice, index-error

Why do i get the indexError?

I have tried to change the slicing to 2001 but i did not help

```
inputs = training_data[:-1] #EVERYTHING EXCEPT last values
outputs = training_data[-1] #last value

training_inputs = inputs[:2000]
training_outputs = outputs[:2000]
testing_inputs = inputs[2000:]
testing_outputs = outputs[2000:]
```

IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.

Comment: `outputs = training_data[-1]` will have a single value so you can not apply slicing on it

Comment: Change your line to `outputs = training_data[-1:]`

Comment: Share these details please: shape of training and test arrays.

Comment: Share these details please: shape of training and test arrays and inputs. Perhaps you want to use: `inputs = training_data[:, :-1]` and `outputs = training_data[:,-1]`.

Answer (score 2):

This problem occurs when You are trying to index into a scalar non-iterable value.

```
>> data = [3, 6, 9]
>> result = data[0] # gives you result=3
>> print(result[0]) # Error
```

Comment: what is the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Because `output` is not a list, and therefore it is not possible to perform slice operations. 
If you want `output` to be a list you can use this trick:

```
outputs = training_data[-1:]
```